# How to get context.params in V2 firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to migrate my firebase functions to V2.In firebase V1 I did:

```
exports.onOpenCourse = functions.firestore.
  document("courses/{courseId}") 
  .onUpdate(
    (change, context) => { 
      ...
      const id = context.params.courseId
      ...
```

So I was able to use the info in "context".As I understand, in V2 I now should do something like:

```
const { onDocumentCreated, document } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
onDocumentCreated( 
  { document: ""courses/{courseId}",},   
  (event) => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const info = snapshot.data();
```

How do I get `context.params` info in firebase functions V2?

The relevant example in the docs seems to still use V1: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

I guess the core issue is that I am confused about exactly what these new functions are returning.
For example: According to the docs I found `https.onCall` returns `any`. Can I count on any to always contain `params` and `data`?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https.md#httpsoncall

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at the best possible documentation.  Use [this reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd) instead, which lets you compare v1 and v2 easily.

The parameters you want are in the `event` object provided to the function.  There is no longer a "context" to use.

```
const { onDocumentCreated, document } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
onDocumentCreated( 
  { document: "courses/{courseId}" },   
  (event) => {
    const courseId = event.params.courseId;
```

The second link to documentation you provided won't be helpful at all because it's for callable functions, which are not the same as Firestore functions.

If you feel that some page of documentation is inaccurate or unhelpful, you should send feedback to Firebase using the "send feedback" button at the top of any page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit my original question to reflect your answer and my understanding of it. Did I get this right? Are there an other places short of the source code to see all the extra parameters and options for the new firevase functions?

Comment: You really shouldn't edit the question to ask new questions - it effectively invalidates the answer you were given to the original question (and it wasn't a wrong answer, I assure you).  Others might be interested in your original question with the provided answer.  Please post your new question separately and provide the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Each post should have one question and one accepted answer to that question.  I am going to respectfully remove the content you added so that the original Q/A are preserved correctly for the future.

Comment: If you want to better understand why it's problematic for questions to be changed after they're answered like this, I strongly recommend [reading this Q and A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between functions from v1 and v2 is, that v2 needs to have `req.data` or `req.context` in order to retrieve either data or context. In v1 u've got directly parameter of data and context.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer to specifically where the `context` is coming from, look at Dougs answer (It's `event.params`). For anyone who wants a bit of guidance on how to navigate firebases patch documentation, here is my current understanding and how I got to it:

What I find confusing is that the examples in the docs only touch the base cases and often leave all the additional config and the exact data structures beind handed over unclear.

Here, the short example imports FirestoreEvent: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#writing-triggered_functions

From that I am guessing that the event that gets passed is of type FirestoreEvent as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.firestoreevent

But here I dont see the data.data() function I was expecting. This is probably coming from the parent CloudEvent: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.cloudevent.md#cloudeventdata

...but here the documentation gets even sparser and `data: T;` does not say much about what return value can be expected.

So AFAIK I can count on `database, document, location, namespace, params` to be present in the return value from onDocumentCreated as well as `data.data()` which will give me the content of the Firestore document in question.

Also, on the meta level I found this video very informative: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbDAmvUwo5c